# solved 2d game camera follow with translate, im having trouble articulating in my mind how it works, what is keeping camera centered on the player?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, camera, translate

I got something working but cannot interpret in my mind, how is it painting every picture with the player in the middle by taking its original position away from where it is painting everything, my brain is addled.

I would like to know why it is working

```
public static Integer ufox = 102,ufoy = 115;


public void paint (Graphics g){
    g.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000);
    g.translate(-ufox+102,-ufoy+115);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
    //backround enemies etc
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawString(ufo,ufox,ufoy);//this is the player!
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
}


public void run() {
    while(true){
        ufox=//game logic
        ufoy=//game logic
        try{Thread.sleep(20);}catch(Exception e){}  
        repaint();  
    }
}

//key listener and main...
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I cant edit it!! its saying rob wont let me!

Comment: the question is I want to know why that the player stays in the centre of the screen when i translate -ufox+102 and -ufoy+115, whats working to keep player in the centre!?

Comment: there edited it succesfully

Comment: It's possible that the location is due to the layout manager. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for better help

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue of relative coordinates.  If you imagine yourself moving in the real world, you can conceptualize it either as your coordinates changing to reflect your movement, or EVERYTHING ELSE'S coordinates changing (in the opposite direction) while your coordinates stay the same.  A coordinate transform like the one in your code can translate between these two (absolute and relative) coordinate systems.

Comment: i suspected that was the case, i just wondered why taking away the postion of the world and adding the coordinates of the player would simulate that

Comment: you're actually just subtracting the player's coordinates from the world coordinates - the +102 and +115 are just an offset to keep the player in the center of the window.  This subtraction maintains the distances between the player and the world objects, but keeps the player at a fixed position (the offset).

Comment: ah yes i see it now, once i found translate i stopped thinking and started guessing :P thanks